# Create an updating animation similar to the facebook iphone app

Tags: iphone

I have a scrollview with all my data to be showed and I want the user to trigger it being updated. The user should pull the scrollview downwards, then a small view will be shown that was previously hidden and that says: "updating" or "release to update".

Look at the iPhone facebook app and you will see what I am talking about.
They did it pretty awesome, they have a small animation that and an arrow that makes it easy and intuitive.

However when trying to replicate this behaviour I have found that the UI is blocked until the scrollview delegate function was run. This is impractical because I want to update the UI from that scrollview delegate function. 
So when the user holds the scrollview in a dragging motion, there should be a small animation or so that tells him to release it or hold it longer.

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{    
    CGPoint topOffset = CGPointMake(0, 20);

    if (self.contentOffset.y < 0 )
    {        
        labelUpdate.text = @"Release to update.";

        //do something here to update the UI
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers,

ultimately I have chosen this solution:
https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh

because it simple and it works. Additionally I have refactored the ViewController shown there into a simple UIView type that you can comfortably use with any UIScrollView derived class.

A link with code will follow shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Search google for pull down to refresh

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look into the Three20 library. Chances are that functionality has been incorporated into that library so you don't have to make it from scratch. (I haven't looked into the Three20 library for awhile so I can't confirm or deny this for sure, sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use an existing framework. A couple of them are mentioned [here](http://iosdevgoodies.joostschuur.com/pull-and-release-refresh-for-table-views).

Answer (score 0):

#### Three20's TTTableViewController

The first time I saw this functionality was in the Tweetie(now Twitter) app and now the Facebook app. The first developer of the Facebook app created an open Framework called Three20 and coincidentally Three20's framework has a demo twitter app on [github](https://github.com/facebook/three20/tree/master/samples/TTTwitter/). To use the 'pull to refresh' functionality though you might have to use Three20's TTTableViewController which uses url paths to keep track of navigation so you might have to adapt your app to use that but there are plenty of tutorials for Three20 like [this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/656/introduction-to-three20).